Could I package jar files in my python library
I am working on a python library which connects to ibm mq and reads messages from it.
To achieve this we have used JPype.
There are couple of jar files which needs to be loaded in jvm before my library could connect to MQ. These jar files are com.ibm.mq.allclient 9.4.0 and org.json .
We have a bamboo build in place which read the code from GitHub and packages it into a wheel and uploads on pypi.
I don’t want users to be responsible for getting the required jars instead I want to package it within my library .
Is packaging required jar files in wheel a good idea ?
Is it against any best practices or design patterns  ?
Any help or suggestions are highly appreciated
I have tried packaging it together and it works.

com.ibm.mq.allclient is part of IBM MQ and is usually subject to IBM's license terms. Including it in your python library may involve copyright issues, so ensure legality.

@life888888 I agree it’s a jar file strictly related to ibm mq but it’s readily available on maven and doesn’t need any license

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.ibm.mq/com.ibm.mq.allclient/9.4.0.0, Licenses Section , IBM International Program License Agreement https://www14.software.ibm.com/cgi-bin/weblap/lap.pl?li_formnum=L-RZND-SLUBFC

@life888888 Thanks for pointing it out my bad I missed that part but it happens so I have the license so I am legally covered
